# Implicit def for Play! 2.2 error handling

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, implicit-conversion, implicit

Hey hoping someone can help me with this. I'm right now trying to write an `implicit def` that can pick up on a specific `java.net.ConnectException` and return a `ServiceUnavailable` instead of an `InternalServerError`. Here's the existing controller method that looks very similar to a lot of other errors:

```
  def list = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    resource.Messaging.forClient(clientId.get).eitherRaw match {
      case Right(o) =>
        Ok( o )
      case Left(e) =>
        logger.error("Error occured attempting to update message.")
        logger.error(ErrorWriter.writeString(e))
        InternalServerError
    }
  }
```

Right now, I can't get an implicit def to pick up on the `e` above. Not sure where to begin. Here's some pseudo-code on what I'm trying to write:

```
implicit def handleConnectException(e: java.net.ConnectionException) = {
  logger.error(ErrorWriter.writeStackTrace(e))
  ServiceUnavailable
}
```

I do know that the `ConnectException` contains a message, so does it need to be `ConnectException[String]`?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: `InternalServerError` is an acceptable return value, so the compiler will never go looking for implicit conversions. You will have to explicitly replace `InternalServerError` with `handleConnectException(e)`.